# Send multiple columns in Spark Dataframe to an external API and store the result in a separate column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a spark dataframe which has 40+ columns. and millions of rows. 
I want to create another column, which takes in say 5 columns from the above dataframe, pass each row of the 5 columns to separate Api(which takes these 5 values and returns some data) and store the result in the column.

For simplicity I use the following example:
Say I've the following dataframe. And I want to send each row of "food" and "price" to an API, which returns a result, and it is stored in a separate column called "combine"

Input:

```
+----+------+-----+
|name|food  |price|
+----+------+-----+
|john|tomato|1.99 |
|john|carrot|0.45 |
|bill|apple |0.99 |
|john|banana|1.29 |
|bill|taco  |2.59 |
+----+------+-----+
```

Output:

```
+----+------+-----+----------+
|name|food  |price|combined  |
+----+------+-----+----------+
|john|tomato|1.99 |abcd      |
|john|carrot|0.45 |fdg       |
|bill|apple |0.99 |123fgfg   |
|john|banana|1.29 |fgfg4wf   |
|bill|taco  |2.59 |gfg45gn   |
+----+------+-----+----------+
```

I created a UDF to look at each row:

```
val zip = udf {
(food: String, price: Double) =>
    val nvIn = new NameValue
    nvIn.put("Query.ID", 1234)
    nvIn.put("Food", food)
    nvIn.put("Price", price)
    val nvOut = new NameValue

    val code: Code = getTunnelsClient().execute("CombineData", nvIn, nvOut) // this is calling the external API
    nvOut.get("CombineData")     //this is stored the result column
  }

  def test(sc: SparkContext, sqlContext: SQLContext): Unit = {
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    val df = Seq(
      ("john", "tomato", 1.99),
      ("john", "carrot", 0.45),
      ("bill", "apple", 0.99),
      ("john", "banana", 1.29),
      ("bill", "taco", 2.59)
    ).toDF("name", "food", "price")


    val result = df.withColumn("combined", zip($"food", $"price"))
    result.show(false)

  }
```

This method works, however I'm concerned since I'm looking at each row of the dataframe, and I have millions of such rows, it won't be as performant on the cluster

Is there any other way I can do it(say using spark-sql), possibly without using a udf ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend using the type safe `spark` `Dataset` api to send your rows of data to the api.

This involves parsing your `Dataframe` rows into a `scala` `case` `class` using the `as` function and then executing the `map` function on your `Dataset\Dataframe` to send it to the api and return another `case class` representing your `Output`.

Although strictly not `spark sql` using the `Dataset` api still allows you to benefit from most of the optimizations that are available in `spark sql`

```
case class Input(name: String, food: String, price: Double)
case class Output(name: String, food: String, price: Double, combined: String)

val df = Seq(
  ("john", "tomato", 1.99),
  ("john", "carrot", 0.45),
  ("bill", "apple", 0.99),
  ("john", "banana", 1.29),
  ("bill", "taco", 2.59)
).toDF("name", "food", "price")

df.as[Input].map(input => {
    val nvIn = new NameValue
    nvIn.put("Query.ID", 1234)
    nvIn.put("Food", input.food)
    nvIn.put("Price", input.price)
    val nvOut = new NameValue
    getTunnelsClient().execute("CombineData", nvIn, nvOut)
    Output(input.name, input.food, input.price, nvOut.get("CombineData"))
}).show(false)
```